# IOS/Xcode: Name button created in storyboard name so it can be disabled

Tags: ios, uibutton, disabled-control

I have a button created in storyboard for taking a photo that is wired to an action.  The button says "Take Photo".

If no camera is present, I would like to disable this button with something like following:

```
[btnOutlet setEnabled:FALSE];
```

How do I give the button a name or otherwise identify it so that I can disable it.  IOS newb here so if you could provide code i.e. where I put this info I would appreciate it.  Thank you.

Here is code I am working with currently.

```
   if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
  //would like to change this alert to just disable the take photo button created in storyboard          
            UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                  message:@"Device has no camera"
                                                                 delegate:nil
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                        otherButtonTitles: nil];

            [myAlertView show];

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `@interface`, add the following code.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *theButton;
```

And control-click from the button in the storyboard to the code you've just typed. There should be a white indicator on the left of the code which indicates that the button has been linked.

You can now disable the button as such.

```
[self.theButton setEnabled: NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIButton` inherits from `UIControl`, whose property `enabled` could be set to `NO` to achieve this.

```
btnOutlet.enabled = NO;
```